# How to display actions similar to one another for proper UX

Tags: interface, notification, call-to-action, warnings

The company I work for have a Search widget which will allow them to search for petrol station sites in the database. A User is able to have a "Saved Search" which will allow them to re-run a detailed Search they have previously done.

However, a new piece of functionality is that the User will be updated, by a notification, when their Saved Search has been updated in the background (I.E: Site information has changed, or new prices are available).

[image]

However, we need to let the User refresh the widget or dismiss the notification (which will go to another area). But at the top right of the widget we have 4 icons:

1. Refresh
2. Settings
3. Maximise
4. Close

I am just wondering if this would be considered good UX? I made the "Refresh" label a call to action button because that is the favourable direction the User should be steered in. I contemplated using icons but I didn't want "Refresh" and "Dismiss / Close" to interfere with the main widget icons listed above.

Any help would be great on this one. 
Thanks.

Comment: How is the refresh button on the notification different to the refresh button on the UI? They appear to do the same thing.

Comment: Hah I challenged the same point but I was told using the widget's specific icon would only refresh that one widget. Whereas the "Refresh" label in the notification would refresh active 'linked' widgets that were associated with the change.

Comment: So, there's a larger UI beyond the widgets... Couldn't you show the notification there (providing you are intending to update ALL widgets)?

Comment: not necessarily due to the UI allowing more than one instance of the same widget and the User may wish to only refresh the updates for one and not all. I'm not a coder so not sure of the possibilities but from a UX point of view it did seem more streamlined to have it notify the User on the widget in question, especially if they are already running the now updated Saved Search.

Comment: ...but the refresh button on the notification refreshes ALL widgets? - You have a Global command on a Local notification - I think that's the problem right there. You might be able to solve it linguistically ("Refresh all") or logistically (Remove the refresh command completely from the notification) but you probably need to rethink how your interface handles the distinction between global and local actions.

Comment: I think lack of proper message make us to think that both the refresh button and icon are same, but it's not. The icon is just a widget refresh and the refresh button in the notification is a refresh linked components. Am I right? If it's true, it's better to rename the button to make more clarity to action (eg: refresh search). You can also use the support of the description to make the user understand the consequences of the refresh action (in notification).

Comment: Also if we need more users to do refresh in notification, then give more importance to refresh button, ignore the big dismiss button instead replace it with a ‘close’ icon of size 12px.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't recognize the buttons in the notification. They don't seem like buttons. Give them more visual attention, and place them below the text. Because your message contains more lines, it feels better to **offer the options below the text** instead of next to the text.

[image]

From your comments I understand the both refresh buttons don't have the same functionality. I'd **make the labels in your notification more clear**, e.g:

*Do you want to refresh to see this update?*

`Refresh search` / `Refresh results` or `Dismiss`

Answer (score 0):

As per my point of view the notification banner two buttons needs to be changed. 
It must be like:

[image]

So, that user do not confuse in refresh buttons.